# Dart App Organising Sub-module(s)

Tags: module, dart, project-management, dart-polymer

This question comes in two parts.  The first can be summed up by [Public Image Limited](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/This_Is_What_You_Want..._This_Is_What_You_Get), "*This is what you want / This is what you get.*"

I'll keep the question simple by pointing to the tutorial:

- [Define a Custom Element](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/tutorials/polymer-intro/) Dart tutorial

I '*decided*' that I'd like to treat different elements as project assets (so to speak).  So I made a sub-folder: named: **components**, that sits below the ***$/web/*** folder, per:

- [enchilada - Pub Package Layout](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/package-layout.html)

Something like this:

```
enchilada/
   :
  web/
    index.html
    main.dart
    style.css
    components/
        tut_stopwatch.html
        tut_stopwatch.dart
```

When I did this: the **[Dart Editor](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/editor/)** becomes very confused.  So firstly, I need to specify "*what I want*" and then describe, "*What I get*" [got]

**I want**:

- Dart to let me put sub-modules in subordinate folders.
- In this case custom elements like "tut_stopwatch", *with appropriate adjustments* for path changes (which I did).
- Ideally, I'd prefer if Dart could integrate subordinate modules at multiple levels.
- You might consider a custom UI element like a '*panel*' that is a '*container*' for several nested sub-components.

**I get**:

- A slew of compilation errors.  These errors cycle: they "resolve" and later "reappear".
- I closed Dart Editor [1.2.0-release], Dart SDK [1.2.0] and restarted -- The problem persists.
- The '***error***' centres on **polymer**, *viz*.:

> ```
>  Target of URI does not exist: 'package:../polymer/polymer.dart'
>  Annotation can be only constant variable or constant constructor invocation
>  Classes can only extend other classes
>  Annotation can be only constant variable or constant constructor invocation
> ```

- I think not finding '*polymer*' is a symptom.  Dart Editor cycles: find **<->** not_find

The cause of this behaviour appears to be me having moved the two files:

1. tute_stopwatch.html, and
2. tute_stopwatch.dart ...

Into the [sub-]**components/** folder as shown (*above*).  The error stems from the import for polymer in the file:

- components/**tute_stopwatch**.dart

Code as follows (Dart build errors as comments):

```dart
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

@CustomTag('tute-stopwatch')                  // <-- Target of URI does not exist: 'package:polymer/polymer.dart'
class TuteStopwatch extends PolymerElement {  // <-- Annotation can be only constant variable or constant constructor invocation
  @observable String counter='00:00';         // <-- Classes can only extend other classes
                                              //     Undefined class 'PolymerElement'
  TuteStopwatch.created() : super.created();

    :
} // TutStopwatch class
```

One thing to point-out is that the Dart Editor makes a Windows [Junction link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point) to the **packages/** folder in every sub-folder.  That would be a [symlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) on Linux or Mac.  So the packages file path should function OK.

I'm looking for a strategy to get what I want?  To have sub-folders for different modules or '*features*' with Dart and Dart Editor in development?  Thanks in advance ... /w

---

```
v02 ... Added code for import polymer error.
v01 ... Original query.
```

Comment: Polymer elements in subfolders of web is supported. You don't need much of a strategy. Maybe you can add some more code (how your import statments look like).

Comment: Hi.  Thanks Gunter, that was a good clue.  It looks like the issue involves how Dart Editor links to the Packages/ folder on Windows.  I will make edits to the question as suggested.

Comment: I think you just have a syntax error somewhere. These error messages make no sense at all at this positions and I'm pretty sure they have nothing to do with your project structure. That superflous colon between constructor and closing curly brace is from minimizing your example before posting I guess?

Comment: @Gunter; thanks.  Can't tell if there's an error.  The program runs and I can see modifications (like a colour change) come through when I run it with Dartium.  (I'm pretty sure this should be a bug, see answer below).

Comment: I read your answer but that doesn't make much sense. I work fulltime with Dart since several months (most of the time with Polymer) and I haven't seen anything similar. What you can do if DartEditor shows weird error messages is execute 'Reanalyze Sources' in the context menu of your application directory in DartEditor.

Comment: I created an answer because the text was to long for a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue I believe.  I am hoping that people who find a better way out of this kind of *cul de sac* will also post better alternatives.  This '*solution*'(?) is quite indelicate and although the application runs correctly (as written) I still have errors in the [**Dart Editor**](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/editor/) *Problems* tab..

At least I know this produces an app that works according to the code I am reading.  I don't think I have a syntax error with the line:

```
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
```

The [demo code](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/tutorials/polymer-intro/) works and [**Dart Editor**](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/editor/) reports an error.  So yes I agree, the "*messages make no sense*" and they are wrong; because the code runs just fine with some unique test values (see below).  So imho, the **Dart Editor** has a ***problem***.  If anyone can confirm this, we can report a bug.

The way I got-out of this problem was:

1. Close the **Dart Editor**
2. Remove the **build/** directory
3. Restart **Dart Editor**
4. Run your app.

For testing, I made changes to bot the 'components' files to ensure nothing from an old build was creating side-effects (example: [Define a Custom Element](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/tutorials/polymer-intro/)).

- tut_stopwatch.html ... Changed the colour.
- tut_stopwatch.dart ... Changed the timer increment.

***Volia!*** The demo stopwatch embedded component works with a '*pink*' colour and a '*3 second*' increment.

I want to cross-link this with this question:

- [Dart Editor equivalent of Eclipse command “Project >> **Clean**…”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21512663/dart-editor-equivalent-of-eclipse-command-project-clean)

In moderate and larger sized projects, there's more to keeping dependencies and interactions straight than just a **clean** command.  I think some visibility and better control over the build would be an improvement.

I have ZIP-ped the project folder for this exercise.  If anyone would like a copy I can email it.  Syntax-wise I made NO changes to the demo code except to fix the ":host" bug.  I just moved 2 x files to a **components/** folder.

~ *aloha*

Comment: Hi *gang* ... Update.  This issue is decided as a problem with the **Packages** folder.  Moving-on I've identified a *gotcha* with [tag:Polymer-dart] herself, check: [Invalid Character: fred](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22454022), will.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment so I post it as answer:

I read your answer but that doesn't make much sense.
I work fulltime with Dart since several months (most of the time with Polymer) and I haven't seen anything similar.

What you can do if DartEditor shows weird error messages is execute 'Reanalyze Sources' in the context menu of your application directory in DartEditor.
If this doesn't change the errors, the errors are in your code.

I have never before seen, that the build directory has influence to errors in your web directory.

Dart is very forgiving so it's no surprise that the app runs when DartEditor shows errors/warnings/hints because the analyzer running in DartEditor is not.

Comment: Reanalyse hasn't changed the outcome so far.  When I kill the Dart Editor ...  everything looks good for a short while.  Your comment tells me there's a problem on this installation.

Comment: Dart Editor: 1.2.0; 
Dart SDK: 1.2.0;
Windows 7 SP1

Comment: Maybe a problem with analyzer. Can you post the analyzer version used by your project. When you expand the enchilada/packages directory in DartEditor it shows the version to the right of the package. Have you executed `pub upgrade` (in context menu on pubspec.yaml)?

Comment: Analyzer version shows as: 0.10.5.  I ran Pub Get, to be sure. The problem in "tut_stopwatch.dart" persist around can't find polymer package.  Interesting, when I ran Pub Get a 2nd time, I get an "Access Denied" error.  I closed Dart Editor and restated, almost every 2nd 'Pub Get' wets an "Access Denied" on the "Packages/" directory.

Comment: Usually you want to use `pub upgrade` but that has nothing to do with your `Access Denied` error. Maybe you should delete the content of the pub/cache directory somewhere in your user directory (don't use windows so I don't know exactly where it is). I guess it is a problem with symlinks - windows can't handle them very well.

Comment: Ah well the symlinks used for dart are simply over kill, so I have no doubt Dart Editor could easily confuse itself.  I'm personally concerned at the profligate nature of these links, they are a finite resource on Linux (last time I looked).

Comment: Anyway [pub upgrade] does nothing except tell me there are 10 newer versions of Analyzer and reassures me that: "No dependencies changed."  The cache was in the user area: "c:\Users\william\AppData\Roaming\Pub"

Comment: I don't know what you mean by finite resource on Linux but the Dart team is working to get rid of them because they causes so much trouble on Windows but it might take some while before an alternative solution is ready.

Comment: Don't worry about the 10 newer versions. This are unstable development versions. You need to add a version dependency in pubspec.yaml to enforce that a dev version is downloaded like `polymer: '>=0.10.0-dev.1'. Look at pub.dartlang.org serch for the polymer package and switch to the `versions` tab to see stable and unstable versions..