# InvalidCharacterError: "fred"

Tags: html, dart, dart-polymer, polymer

I am sure his must be a newbie question.  In simple terms I wanted to define my first Polymer-dart component.  Only I keep kicking my toe on the same speed-hump.  To keep things very simple, I've stripped it back to a very simple example.

I did a simple ***rename*** of the example: '**stopwatch**'component from the Dart component Polymer-dart tutorial:

- [**Define a Custom Element**](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/tutorials/polymer-intro)

I had errors similar to the one in the question title, so the renamed component is:

- '***fred***' ... from: '*tute-stopwatch*'

When this is done, I get the error trace below.  It looks to me that the name is my problem.  I confirmed this by running the example after each incremental change (*what else can you do?*).  I retained the file names:

- tute_stopwatch.html
- tute_stopwatch.dart

From the example, and only changed the component label name.  That means a change in 3 x files.

1. index.html

   - <**fred**></**fred**>

     - *from*: <tute-stopwatch></tute-stopwatch>
2. tute_stopwatch.html

   - <polymer-element name="**fred**">

     - *from*: <polymer-element name="tute-stopwatch">
3. tute_stopwatch.dart

   - @CustomTag('**fred**')

     - *from*: @CustomTag('tute-stopwatch')

Although, I can't say having to update **three**(***3***) things for one simple change is ideal, it is still very basic and very simple to '*make*' a new element with Polymer-dart once you have a model definition.

Apart from, *what went wrong?* I guess a second question I can ask is, what does the:

- '*The type name is invalid.*' ... **Mean**?

The question is decidedly a *newbie* question. However because the '*solution*' is not obvious or intuitive, I've missed something.  Oh and the error makes No Sense (to mere mortals).  *Muy gracias* ...

---

## Exception:

```
Uncaught Error: InvalidCharacterError: Registration failed for type 'fred'. The type name is invalid.
Stack Trace: 
#0      _Utils._register (file:///E:/b/build/slave/dartium-win-full-stable/build/src/dart/tools/dom/src/native_DOMImplementation.dart:450)
#1      _Utils.register (file:///E:/b/build/slave/dartium-win-full-stable/build/src/dart/tools/dom/src/native_DOMImplementation.dart:446)
#2      HtmlDocument.register (file:///E:/b/build/slave/dartium-win-full-stable/build/src/build/Release/obj/global_intermediate/blink/bindings/dart/dart/html/HtmlDocument.dart:266)
#3      PolymerDeclaration.registerType (package:polymer/src/declaration.dart:241:22)
#4      PolymerDeclaration.register (package:polymer/src/declaration.dart:164:17)
#5      PolymerDeclaration._register (package:polymer/src/declaration.dart:114:13)
#6      PolymerDeclaration.registerWhenReady (package:polymer/src/declaration.dart:109:14)
#7      _notifyType (package:polymer/src/declaration.dart:476:49)
#8      Polymer.register (package:polymer/src/instance.dart:65:16)
#9      _loadLibrary (package:polymer/src/loader.dart:196:25)
#10     _loadLibraries (package:polymer/src/loader.dart:89:19)
#11     _initPolymerOptimized (package:polymer/src/loader.dart:54:17)
#12     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:710)
#13     _ZoneDelegate.run (dart:async/zone.dart:440)
#14     _CustomizedZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:650)
#15     initPolymer (package:polymer/src/loader.dart:37:33)
#16     main (package:polymer/init.dart:23:22)

Exception: InvalidCharacterError: Registration failed for type 'fred'. The type name is invalid.  undefined (undefined:0:0)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The tag name of polymer elements must contain a dash to differentiate them from standard DOM elements.

Comment: This is an important point, and it isn't documented on [tag:dart-polymer]: [**Custom Elements**](https://www.dartlang.org/polymer-dart/#custom-elements).  It is stated on the [Polymer](http://www.polymer-project.org) web site: [**Creating Elements**](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/creatingelements.html)