# Writing Dart build scripts = builder.dart

Tags: eclipse, build, dart, dart-editor

this should be an easy one for someone to answer.  I want to write a Dart Editor '**build** plugin'.

The first question is where do I look for documentation or a '*how to*'?  My first task is to consider something to help me deal with this issue and clean-up old stuff:

- [Dart editor equivalent of Eclipse Clean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21512663/dart-editor-equivalent-of-eclipse-command-project-clean)

After I get an idea of how to implement a build script; I want to know how to find the dart build files, any caches, etc that may need a bit of a clean-up.  In [eclipse](/questions/tagged/eclipse) you get to tell Eclipse what to clean-up, leading me to the third question.

If I want to add-to or enhance the Dart Editor options menu; where can I look for instructions on doing that?

Answer (score 1):

Currently it is not possible to extend any DartEditor menues. It is planned to allow to add items to the Tools menu but as far as I know work on this has not yet started (see https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=16921).

Normally you don't have anything to clean in Dart.
As far as I know, `pub` is now the preferred build tool.
`pub build` writes only in the `build` directory.
When `web` is built the result goes to `build/web` (similar for `example`, `test`, ...)

The build results are automatically deleted before a new build.

Therefore it should not be necessary to do any clean-up. If you really want to clean something, delete the build directory inside your package.

---

edit-by: Will

> The following snippet is from the current Dart Polymer documentation web page.  I couldn't put it in a comment because I needed to format the code example.  Hope that's OK.

### **build**.dart example:

- https://www.dartlang.org/polymer-dart/

Code

```dart
import 'package:polymer/builder.dart';

void main(List<String> args) {
  lint(entryPoints: ['web/index.html'], options: parseOptions(args));
}
```

Comment: I can definitively confirm that the Packages Cache needs to be purged from time-to-time.  I also foresee other things will/may benefit from a good wash with *soap-n-water*, this observation is based on my understanding that a '**builder**.*dart*' file can be used to implement custom build steps like pre-processing, post-processing, generation, or other steps.

Comment: Cleaning the package cache has nothing to do with building the project. I don't know what you mean by `builder.dart` file. I know `build.dart` which is called by the editor sometimes (AFAIK when some files are updated). I think, if you want to hook into the build process you have to do this using pub transformers. Currently the Dart team is working to make DartEditor use `pub` for such tasks.

Comment: Ok, now I know. You import `builder.dart` but the build file should be named `build.dart` https://www.dartlang.org/tools/editor/build.html